# Regex- to get part of String

Tags: regex, ruby, workato

I have got below string and I need to Get all the values Between **Pizzahut:** and **|**.

```
ABC:2fg45rdvsg|Pizzahut:j34532jdhgj|Dominos:3424232|Pizzahut:3242237|Wendys:3462783|Pizzahut:67688873rg|
```

I have got RegExpression `.scan(/(?<=Pizzahut:)([.*\s\S]+)(?=\|)/)` but it fetches

```
"j34532jdhgj|Dominos:3424232|Pizzahut:3242237|Wendys:3462783|Pizzahut:67688873rg|"
```

**Result should be:** `34532jdhgj,3242237,67688873rg`

Comment: You can use `s.scan(/Pizzahut:([^|]+)/).flatten`, see [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/cKOgpN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```rb
s='ABC:2fg45rdvsg|Pizzahut:j34532jdhgj|Dominos:3424232|Pizzahut:3242237|Wendys:3462783|Pizzahut:67688873rg|'
p s.scan(/Pizzahut:([^|]+)/).flatten
# => ["j34532jdhgj", "3242237", "67688873rg"]
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/cKOgpN) and the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/54Ki75QK4Nrrs0).

It does not look possible that you have `Pizzahut` as a part of another word, but it is possible, use a version with a word boundary, `/\bPizzahut:([^|]+)/`.

The `Pizzahut:([^|]+)` matches `Pizzahut:` and then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than a pipe (with `([^|]+)`).

Note that `String#scan` returns the captures only if a pattern contains a capturing group, so you do not need to use lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're jumping to a **regex** solution here; that input string clearly looks structured to me, and you would probably do better by splitting it on the delimiters to convert it into a *more convenient data structure.*

Something like this:

```
input = "ABC:2fg45rdvsg|Pizzahut:j34532jdhgj|Dominos:3424232|Pizzahut:3242237|Wendys:3462783|Pizzahut:67688873rg"

converted_input = input
  .split('|') #=> ["ABC:2fg45rdvsg", "Pizzahut:j34532jdhgj", ... ]
  .map { |pair| pair.split(':') } #=> [["ABC", "2fg45rdvsg"], ["Pizzahut", "j34532jdhgj"], ... ]
  .group_by(&:first) #=> {"ABC"=>[["ABC", "2fg45rdvsg"]], "Pizzahut"=>[["Pizzahut", "j34532jdhgj"], ... ], "Dominos"=>[["Dominos", "3424232"]], ... ]
  .transform_values { |v| v.flat_map(&:last) }
```

(The above series of transformations is just one possible way; you could probably come up with a dozen similar alternative steps to convert this input into the same hash shown below! For example, by using `reduce` or even the `CSV` library.)

Which gives you the final result:

```
converted_input = {
  "ABC" => ["2fg45rdvsg"],
  "Pizzahut" => ["j34532jdhgj", "3242237", "67688873rg"],
  "Dominos" => ["3424232"],
  "Wendys" => ["3462783"]
}
```

Now that the data is formatted conveniently, obtaining data like your original request becomes trivial:

```
converted_input["Pizzahut"].join(',') #=> "j34532jdhgj,3242237,67688873rg"
```

(Although quite likely it would be more suitable to leave it as an `Array`, not a comma-separated `String`!!)